# Calling a script right after opening a type of file?

Tags: macos

Does any one of you know if it's possible to call a script right after opening a file.

For example : I want to relocate QuickTime in the top-left corner right next to my dock.

I  know how to do it with AppleScript (the location thing) but how can I call this script automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but try watching for changes to some file that is modified when the application opens a document.

Using launchd, you could save this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist` and run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array> 
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>try
tell app "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player"
set position of window 1 to {500, 500}
end
end</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.LSSharedFileList.plist</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It won't work if you open multiple documents in a row, because launchd runs programs only at most every 10 seconds.

Comment: Yep it works but after 10 sec. But not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

[Do Something When - Project](http://www.azarhi.com/Projects/DSW/)

It seems like what you want...I have never personally used it.